# Make Panel Resizable For User

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `[PANEL(1)] > [Dock=Fill]`, and another `[PANEL(2)]` inside set to the same height.

How do I make `[PANEL(2)]` resizable to the user, as they can resize only the width from both sides?

[image: a busy cat]

This is how the panel will look like when the user resize it to a (random area).

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words... well put question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a [`SplitContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) at the root, inside that another, and you'll have 3 panels to actually put your resizable controls in, with draggable splitters in between.

Comment: The answer remains the same. Otherwise you need to clarify an awful lot more than you asked now.

Comment: To expand this answer, both split containers need to be oriented to the horizontal.  That means you'd see two vertical bars used to drag left/right sizing.